# Realizar un buscador en tiempo real en el que se pueda pinchar en los resultados

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

He estado buscando por stack overflow respuestas a esta pregunta y no lo encuentro. Si es cierto que hay múltiples preguntas referidas a buscadores en tiempo real, pero ninguna en la que se pueda clicar en los resultados. Yo ya tengo el buscador realizado, pero quiero que cuando pinches en los resultado ocurra algo. Como en Instagram cuando buscas a un usuario, te salen varias opciones y cuando pulsas te lleva al perfil de esa persona. Muchas gracias de antemano.
Esto es lo que tengo hecho:
Este el el html del buscador y el script:

```
<div id="lateral2">
              <h1>Buscador</h1>
              <div class="form-1-2">
                <label for="buscador">Buscar:</label>
                <input type="text" name="buscador" id="buscador"></input>
              </div>
              <div id="datos">
              </div>

        <script>
          $(buscar_datos());
          function buscar_datos(consulta){
            $.ajax({
              url: 'buscar.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: {consulta: consulta},
            })
            .done(function(respuesta){
              $("#datos").html(respuesta);
            })
            .fail(function(){
              console.log("error");
            })
          }
          $(document).on('keyup', '#buscador', function(){
            var valor = $(this).val();
            if(valor != ""){
              buscar_datos(valor);
            }else{
              buscar_datos();
            }
          });
        </script>
```

Y este es el archivo buscar.php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'root',
    '',
    'crapping',
);

$salida = "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM grupos";
if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT g.nombre, u.nombre FROM grupos AS g INNER JOIN usuarios AS u WHERE u.nombre LIKE '%".$q."%' OR g.nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$resultado = $conn->query($query);
if($resultado->num_rows>0){
    $salida.="<table class='tabla_datos'>
                <tbody>";

    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        $salida.="<tr>
                <td><button id=fila1>".$fila['nombre']."</button></td>
                </tr>";
    }
    
    $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    echo $salida;
    
} else{
    $salida.="No hay todavia ningún grupo que se llame así. Puedes buscar por otro nombre o crear uno.";
}

$conn->close();

?>

<script>
    const fila1 = document.getElementById('fila1');
    fila1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('boton funciona');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Ves algún error/mensaje en la consola?

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro No, si el codigo que tengo funciona bien. El problema es que me gustaria añadir una funcionalidad que al pinchar en los resultados se ejecute un acción.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer problema que veo es que todas las filas van a tener el mismo id (`fila1`), eso va a hacer que el eventListener se aplique exclusivamente al primero y no a los demás. Pero eso será de poca importancia luego (aunque debes asegurarte que todos los elementos van a tener diferente ID) porque vamos a usar jQuery `.on()` en lugar de `addEventListener` para asociar el evento.

El problema que encuentras es porque jQuery trata de manera especial los `<script>` a ejecutar dentro del método `.html()`. No los elimina, pero tampoco lo ejecuta. Podrías usar `globalEval()` o `evalScript()` (como se indica en esta [respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699905/3695983)), pero te recomendaría usar [eventos delegados](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) en lugar de eso.

Explicación un poco básica: los eventos delegados son gestores de eventos para elementos que aún no han sido creados en el DOM. Una vez se creen, jQuery asociará el evento al elemento.

Para el código de la pregunta, eliminaría el `<script>` de buscar.php y añadiría este método en el mismo `<script>` donde se define la función `buscarDatos`:

```javascript
$("#datos").on( "click", "button", function() {
  console.log("Botón funciona");
});
```

Ahí, le estamos diciendo a jQuery: ejecuta esta función cada vez que se pulse en un botón dentro del contenedor `#datos` (aunque ese botón se haya creado después de definir la función).

Comment: Aparte de eso, te recomendaría algunos cambios más: evita los IDs duplicados, no uses tablas para formatear elementos (en este caso una lista es mejor), cambia el tipo del input de "text" a "search"... Aparte, la accesibilidad web es esencial, y habría que hacer algún cambio para relacionar el input con los resultados y alguna cosilla más.

Comment: Muchímas gracias. Voy a intentarlo a ver si me sale. Todos los días se aprende algo. Jeje. Un saludo

Comment: ¡Pero no aceptes la respuesta hasta no saber si te funciona! :P Mira que si luego la pruebas y no te vale. Siempre puedes desmarcarla, pero bueno.

Comment: ¿Y para obtener el contenido de el botón en el que se pincha en la pagina princiàl (no en buscar.php ) como sería?

Comment: @Mariguuan ¿A qué te refieres?